# Book about a blue wolf and werewolves on the run from their evil vampire uncle

Tags: story-identification, books, vampire, werewolf

I am trying to identify a book. These are the details that I recall:

- A blue wolf.
- Two young werewolves (aged 10-14) on the run from their evil vampire uncle.
- This uncle has a ghost vampire brother.
- There were black and white pictures in each chapter.

Answer (score 2):

As Adamant indicated in the comments, this could be J.K. Hawkins's *[My Werewolf Brothers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0982300913)*, second book of the *My Weird Family* series.

> The Adventure Continues… Alice Trivett thought she didn’t have a family. Her mother told her it was just the two of them – that the rest of her relatives were dead. She just forgot to mention they were the living dead. When Alice leaves her vampire cousin’s castle by way of his magic attic, she finds herself face to face with her three werewolf brothers! The brothers are convinced Alice just isn’t cool enough for them – she acts too much like a little sister. Alice is content to find their padlocked attic and say farewell to her flea ridden, slobbering brothers but soon finds herself being dragged through the woods in a wolf-skin costume while her brothers bring her face to face with the one and only BIG BAD WOLF! And with her vampire uncle, Amadeus, breathing down her neck, Alice knows she’d better figure out where her brothers’ attic is, and FAST! My Weird Family Series: My Werewolf Brothers is the second book in this exciting new series. Join Alice as she makes her way through the Monster World meeting more weird and wacky relatives.